# VBA Autofilter a range of columns for dates in the past

Tags: vba, autofilter

I have a count formula to check a range for dates in the past:
=COUNTIFS(BP11:BV499,TODAY()-1)
I would like to create an autofilter that filters the data and shows me the rows in the same range of columns that contain dates in the past.
I am able to filter by 1 or 2 columns but don't know of a way to filter by a range of columns.
anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: suggest to enter your formula in a helper column, then use that column to filter

Comment: A helper column wouldn't help me autofilter to show all the rows that have a date in the past, a helper column can only help me count them. I could be wrong, if so please tell me .

Comment: It's not that hard, just think about it:  Adjust your formula like this: `=COUNTIFS(BP1:BV1,TODAY()-1)>0`, enter it in the helper column, then helper column will show TRUE in all rows your are searching for, then filter that column for values `=TRUE`.

Comment: I was able to make it work with your suggestion of a helper column with a slight variation, here is the formula for anyone searching: =COUNTIFS(BP53:BV53,"<="&TODAY())>0. I was hoping to make this work without a helper column.

Comment: There are many ways this can  be done without a helper column, but then you'll need to learn and combine VBA methods such as `For … Next`, `Arrays`, `AutoFilter` and perhaps `FormatCondition` or `Dictionary`. Just keep studying and learning.